# Not able to use str_to_map with pipe delimiter in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using

```
val df5 = spark.sql("select str_to_map('fruits=banana|sports=football','\\|','=') as json_temp")
```

but the output is not as expected

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_temp                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[f ->, r ->, u ->, i ->, t ->, s ->,  -> , b ->, a ->, n ->, a ->, n ->, a ->, | ->, s ->, p ->, o ->, r ->, t ->, s ->,  -> , f ->, o ->, o ->, t ->, b ->, a ->, l ->, l ->,  ->]|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It is not able to read the delimiter and the separator.

I want the output to be like

```
fruits -> banana, sports -> football
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use four backslashes for regex escapes in Scala:

```
spark.sql("select str_to_map('fruits=banana|sports=football','\\\\|','=') as json_temp").show(false)
+--------------------------------------+
|json_temp                             |
+--------------------------------------+
|[fruits -> banana, sports -> football]|
+--------------------------------------+
```

Or use triple quotes with two backslashes:

```
spark.sql("""select str_to_map('fruits=banana|sports=football','\\|','=') as json_temp""").show(false)
+--------------------------------------+
|json_temp                             |
+--------------------------------------+
|[fruits -> banana, sports -> football]|
+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the pipe character. You can put it inside `[]` :

```scala
val df5 = spark.sql(
  "select str_to_map('fruits=banana|sports=football','[|]','=') as json_temp"
)

//+--------------------------------------+
//| json_temp                            |
//+--------------------------------------+
//|[fruits -> banana, sports -> football]|
//+--------------------------------------+
```